# Theorem 1.27 a) in Diamond, Darmon, Taylor, "Fermat's Last Theorem"

Tags: number-theory, elliptic-curves, modular-forms

I am looking for a reference for part a) of Theorem 1.27 [here](https://www.math.mcgill.ca/darmon/pub/Articles/Expository/05.DDT/paper.pdf) regarding the proof of the growth of coefficients of cusp forms. Theorem 1.24 gives a very sketchy argument of a less specific fact, but I lack the insight to see how to convert the explanation given there into Theorem 1.27 a). The only explanation I have been able to find is that this follows from the Weil Conjectures plus Modularity, but since the Diamond Darmon Taylor notes seek to establish a special case of Modularity, this explanation is certainly not suitable.

Comment: It’s been asked on MO for $\Delta$ instead of cusp forms of weight $2$: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/19169/reference-request-for-a-proof-of-ramanujans-tau-conjecture, but Deligne’s argument (see thread) works in this generality. I think there’s a book by Brian Conrad (see his webpage) but it’s in revision and he says to burn old copies of it. I also heard there was a book by Edixhoven and others that deals with this (about computing coefficients of $\Delta$).

Comment: In weight $2$, the argument is a lot simpler, though, because $a_p(f)$ is the eigenvalue of $T_p$ acting on the $r$-torsion of $J_1(N)$ (where $r\nmid pN$ is a different prime). By Eichler-Shimura, we can then write $a_p=\alpha+p\chi(p)/\alpha$, where $\chi$ is the character of $f$ and $\alpha$ is some eigenvalue of $Frob_p$ on the $r$-adic Tate module of $J_1(N)$. By the Riemann hypothesis on curves (proved by Weil) – specifically $X_1(N)$,  $|\alpha|=\sqrt{p}$, and that concludes.

Comment: The Edixhoven book I mention should be Edixhoven, Couveignes, de Jong, Merkl, Bosman, *Computational Aspects of Modular Forms and Galois Representations*.